# Why am I getting a NumberFormatException trying to parse an integer from string in Android?

Tags: java, android, parseint, numberformatexception

I am looking for an update function for a custom ROM based tool. I used this code http://www.androidsnippets.com/check-for-updates-once-a-day as a base and soon realized that I couldn't use Dropbox for deployment with that code. So I modified the code to download a version.txt file from dropbox. The file contains a single number (the latest Version Code, in this case 11). I need to read that line and parse the string as an integer to compare with the current versionCode and trigger a download if an update exists.
All the code works, except for parsing the int from the txt file.

Heres my code:

```
    private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
public void run() {
    try {

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"BPversion.txt");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);

        int curVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.JB15613.BPcolorTool", 0).versionCode;
        System.out.println(line);
        int newVersion = 0;
        System.out.println(line);

        try {
            newVersion = Integer.parseInt(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + nfe);
        }

        if (newVersion > curVersion) {
            mHandler.post(showUpdate);
        }    
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Caught exception");

    }
}
```

And I get this exception:

```
    Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "11"
```

When I apply breakpoints and run the debugger, it crashes at the parseInt line.

11 looks like a valid int to me!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `newVersion = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());` try this.

Comment: is UTF-8 file or ASCII? Are you sure "11" is a valid characters?

Comment: `line = "11"; newVersion = Integer.parseInt(line);` does this work?

Comment: @ Nikolay, I cannot define the integer this way, it must be parsed from the txt file. Also, I have tried both UTF-8 and ASCII

Comment: @ vini- adding trim() function works if the text file is ANSI. It does not work with UTF-8. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line ends CRLF ,so , need call function trim() in String ..

```
int newVersion = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
```

Comment: @BrianRoach, what is the point of copy-pasting someone's earlier comment as an answer?

Comment: **A comment isn't an answer**

Comment: Okay, after adding the function trim() and changing the encoding of the text file to ANSI, the code worked! However, UTF-8 encoding will not work with this code. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to what has already been stated:

Your problem is that your 11 is not able to parse to an int, the underlying root of which is that you are parsing white space as part of your string.

As already stated the trim() method should remove the problem but If you wanted to know what was causing the problem and why this fixes it then that is the reason.

You are not trying to parse "11", you are parsing something like "11 " or " 11" which is a different thing. The spaces from the file you are reading from are being included in your string as it is passed into the parseInt method.

Again, I know this has been answered but I thought this additional information would still be useful.

Answer (score -1):

**Try to print the value of line in  the logcat or screen or ui.**

Check what will be coming.A valid int is coming or any other is coming.

i think **line does not cotains valid int.**

```
 Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

**The above exception is thrown due to invalid int format or number format.**

Check the values of line

Comment: I am printing it a few different times, at different spots to see if it changes. It always prints 11