# kotlin app crashes when going one to another activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i have 3 activitiy when i start my app i can go 1 activity to second but i cant go third it crashes

this is code of my third( last activity )

```
class thirdActivity3 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var textView: TextView
    private lateinit var textView2: TextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third3)


        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2)

        val extras = intent.extras

        if(extras != null){
            textView.text = extras.getString("NAME") //getString("NAME","")
            textView2.text = extras.getInt("AGE").toString() //getInt("AGE",0).toString()




        }
    }
}
```

and this is my second activity

```
class secondActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var inputTextAge:EditText
    private lateinit var finishButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2)
        inputTextAge=findViewById(R.id.inputTextAge)
        finishButton=findViewById(R.id.finishButton)


        val extras = intent.extras
        var name = ""
        if (extras != null){
            name=extras.getString("PERSON_NAME","")



        }


        finishButton.setOnClickListener {

            val age = finishButton.text.toString().toInt()
            val intent = Intent(this,thirdActivity3::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("NAME",name)
            intent.putExtra("AGE",age)



            startActivity(intent)



        }
    }
}
```

i am trying to make wizard for learning but my code have some problems. i have 3 activitys in kotling but when i go second activity to third it's stopping but its workd when i going first to second

```
2020-11-27 18:50:41.472 19343-19343/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 19343
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Finish"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.myapplication.secondActivity2$onCreate$1.onClick(secondActivity2.kt:33)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

this is from logcat

Comment: Add the stacktrace (crash information) from the logcat, please

Comment: i have updated post

Comment: There is a parsing from text to string that is crashing the app. Is there any `EditText` that contains the word `Finish` ? Are you doing in any place `Integer.parseInt(...)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NumberFormatException trying to parse an integer from string in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814069/why-am-i-getting-a-numberformatexception-trying-to-parse-an-integer-from-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error message, it looks like your problem is this line:

```
val age = finishButton.text.toString().toInt()
```

The error is saying that you're trying to parse the string "Finish" as a number.  It makes sense from this line that you're doing that.  You have a button named "Finish".  You get the `text` from the button and then call `toInt()` on that text, and you get this error.

What do you expect this line to do?  Why do you expect querying a button's text to return an integer that represents age?

Comment: ohhh i fixedd it thx you broo <3 but right now i can go third activity but in activity only outputing ints not strings

Comment: This new thing a separate problem/question.  Please complete this question by accepting the answer and/or upvoting, and then put together a new question that presents your new problem.  Describe well your expected behavior, input and output, and also explain the output you're getting.